# laravel blade @auth and @guest

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I have written a custom authentication module which will verify a users credentials from an external API this works fine and the user can log in and logout however i cant use @auth and @guest in a blade template. I am setting a session variable "authenticated" => true but it doesn't seem to work and despite being logged in just shows me the guest content.

laravel 5.8

I think that I am not setting the correct session variables any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Cam

Answer (score 0):

ok so I made a silly mistake, I was returning a view that needed data from a controller instead of calling the controller I returned the view with no data in it which is why i was making myself confused.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone comes across this and has the same issue as me the session variable that needs to be set is something like this where the 59ba... is a token

$request->session()->put('login_web_59ba36addc2b2f9401580f014c7f58ea4e30989d', 1);